# What is this projection matrix doing?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Let’s say we have a $m\times d$ zero mean multivariate Gaussian matrix $X$. Its covariance matrix is $X^{T}X$. Let $V$ be the $d\times d$ matrix of eigenvectors of $X^{T}X$, with the columns sorted in descending order of eigenvalues.

Let’s say we know that the last $k$ eigenvectors correspond to noise. We zero out the first $d-k$ eigenvectors, call this matrix $W$, then construct a projection matrix $P = W^{T}W$.

My question is, what exactly is $P$ doing? If we want to analyse only the noise component of $X$, why don’t we just multiply $X$ by $W$? Why is the projection matrix necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying $X$ by $W$ gives you transformed data. Multiplying $X$ by $P$ gives you $X$ again ($P$ is the identity matrix because the eigenvectors are orthogonal).

Observe that
$$
\text{Var}\left[W^T X\right] = W^T\text{Var}\left[X\right]W  \approx W^T\frac{1}{n}X^TXW
$$

You're writing the spectral decomposition as

$$
X^TX = V 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \lambda_d
\end{bmatrix}
 V^T
$$
which implies that
$$
V^TX^TX V = V^TV 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \lambda_d
\end{bmatrix}
 V^TV
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \lambda_d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so
$$
\text{Var}\left[W^T X\right] 
\approx
n^{-1}
 \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \lambda_{d-k}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$